# fpdf Tables: Cell Splitting/Merging

Tags: pdf, merge, split, fpdf

I am trying to generate a PDF which contains a table with split/merged cells looking like so:

Cell | Cell       | Cell
Cell | C1 | C2 | Cell
       | C1 | C2 | Cell

I am using fpdf and was referred to the multicell table script, which I have used previously in similar pdfs. I looked at the code and can't think of a way to make the cells split or merge according to what I need. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 3):

Just do it manually so that the cell width becomes the sum of both of the merged cells.

As per your example there:

```php
$column_widths = ["50","50","50","50"];

// First row.
$pdf->Cell($column_widths[0],                     5, "Cell", "", 0, "C", false);
$pdf->Cell($column_widths[1] + $column_widths[2], 5, "Cell", "", 0, "C", false);
$pdf->Cell($column_widths[3],                     5, "Cell", "", 0, "C", false);

// Second row.
$pdf->Cell($column_widths[0], 5, "Cell", "", 0, "C", false);
$pdf->Cell($column_widths[1], 5, "C1",   "", 0, "C", false);
$pdf->Cell($column_widths[2], 5, "C2",   "", 0, "C", false);
$pdf->Cell($column_widths[3], 5, "Cell", "", 0, "C", false);

// Third row.
$pdf->Cell($column_widths[0], 5, "",     "", 0, "C", false);
$pdf->Cell($column_widths[1], 5, "C1",   "", 0, "C", false);
$pdf->Cell($column_widths[2], 5, "C2",   "", 0, "C", false);
$pdf->Cell($column_widths[3], 5, "Cell", "", 0, "C", false);
```

Or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use EasyTable
https://github.com/fpdf-easytable/fpdf-easytable

A simple example:

```
$table=new easyTable($pdf, 3, 'width:100;');

 $table->easyCell('Text 1', 'rowspan:2; valign:T'); 
 $table->easyCell('Text 2', 'bgcolor:#b3ccff; rowspan:2');
 $table->easyCell('Text 3');
 $table->printRow();

 $table->rowStyle('min-height:20');
 $table->easyCell('Text 4', 'bgcolor:#3377ff; rowspan:2');
 $table->printRow();

 $table->easyCell('Text 5', 'bgcolor:#99bbff;colspan:2');
 $table->printRow();

 $table->endTable();
```